# Python importlib.resources.files() throws UnicodeDecodeError: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-unicode, python-importlib, data-files

I am creating a Python package that needs certain data files in order to work. I've been looking for a way to include these data files with the package installation. I found a way using `importlib.resources.files()`. However, I'm receiving an error when I try to decode the objects I am returned.

I've created a barebones example package. The package tree is as follows.

```
.
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── one.ppn
│   └── two.rhn
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.py

1 directory, 5 files
```

The entire point of this example package is to be able to access `one.ppn` and `two.rhn`. This is done by identifying absolute file paths, and then savings them as constants to be imported. The code is located in `__init__.py`.

```
# package.__init__.py

from importlib.resources import files


PACKAGE_DATA = files('package')

KEYWORD_PATH = PACKAGE_DATA.joinpath('one.ppn')

print(PACKAGE_DATA)
print(KEYWORD_PATH)

CONTEXT_PATH = PACKAGE_DATA.joinpath('two.rhn').read_text()
```

I have created an editable install (`pip3 install -e ../Package`) in a seperate directory. If I then import `package`, I receive the following output.

```
/home/millertime/Desktop/Package/package
/home/millertime/Desktop/Package/package/one.ppn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/millertime/Desktop/Test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package
  File "/home/millertime/Desktop/Package/package/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    CONTEXT_PATH = PACKAGE_DATA.joinpath('two.rhn').read_text()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1256, in read_text
    return f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

You can see that `importlib` is functioning perfectly at first, and has correctly identified the absolute file paths to my data files. However, when I try to decode to a `str` that I can actually use, I receive a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

I'm not sure if my `pyproject.toml` file is relevant, so I'm going to include it here. The only part I could see contributing to the problem is `[tool.setuptools.package-data]`.

```
# pyproject.toml

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "package"
version = "1.0.0"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = [
    "package"
]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
package = [
    "one.ppn",
    "two.rhn"
]
```

I researched other instances of this error and tried a couple of things to solve it.

1. I attempted to create my own decoding method using a `with` statement and the `read_bytes()` method of the object, but received the same error.
2. I saw that many of the errors were related to the encoder, and thought that maybe I was using the wrong one (`utf-8`). I installed `chardet` to tell me what kind I should use, and received another error relating to being unable to decode due to an "invalid continuation byte".

It seems to me that this an internal problem with `importlib`. I don't see how it could be related to my data file types, given it's just a string representing a file path, not the actual data of the file.

I am currently using Python 3.9.2 on a Raspberry Pi 4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `byte 0xe0 in position 0` -> the very first byte of the file is problematic. Does the file actually contain text data?  Can you show us the few bytes of the file, and the text that you expect them to represent?

Comment: @snakecharmerb The bytes do not represent the file data, they represent the file path.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks to me as if the error is in `read_text()`, so it is trying to decode the contents of the file that the path points to. (But I have covid at the moment, perhaps it has addled my brain)

Comment: @snakecharmerb You're right. I'm an idiot. Thanks for solving my problem, will use the proper method this time. Go ahead and post as an answer if you would like.

Comment: Our own bugs are the hardest to see :)  I don't think this needs an answer, it's unlikely to be of use to future visitors.  Shame though, it's a nicely constructed question.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for your help, good luck with COVID.